# How to modify text value in Bat file using Nsis script

Tags: nsis

I have builded Nsis script successfully.I have bat file in my project.Inside bat file i have two variables with default values as follows

```
 JVM_DLL=c:\program Files\java\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

 Home_path=c:\opt\projectName
```

If the user wants to modify the value for JVM_DLL and Home_path that should be written in batch file.How to do this? I donot know how to write in batch file using Nsis script?

I have tried following codes.but its not working

```
 StrCpy $JVM_DLL "jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"
 ${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\batch.bat" "JVM_DLL" "=$JVM_DLL" $R0
 ${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\resource\batch.bat" "HOME_PATH" "=$INSTDIR" $R0
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the 2 values in the `.bat` file that is also launching `makensis.exe`, use the `/D` command line switch to define those values for the nsis script.

In your example, given your 2 .bat variables:

```
makensis.exe /DJVM_DLL=%JVM_DLL% /DHome_path=%Home_path% yourscript.nsi
```

Comment: @Seki.thank you.In my nsi script where am i going to give this command?? Still i dont use makensis.exe in my nsi file? can you please explain me?

Comment: makensis.exe /DJVM_DLL=%JVM_DLL% /DHome_path=%$INSTDIR% setup.nsi.I have given this inside function.i got the error message as "Invalid command: makensis.exe"

Comment: @ILLA: You tell in the question that you have a .bat in your project. Do you use that .bat to start the nsis compilation? If no, how do you compile your script?

Comment: BTW, `makensis.exe` is the command that compiles a nsis script into an executable.

Comment: thanks.I have nsis plugin in my eclipse.from that i could run the nsi file without using makensis.exe.I know there is makensis.exe.but i didnot use for compile.

Comment: no need to run through command line using makensis.exe.modify the values for batch file.